# SDL 2 + OpenGL 1.3 - No light

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

I have this project for Win/Linux that has to use OpenGL 1.3 because later on will be ported to another platform that only supports that version.

I have a basic scene with a directional light and using GL_COLOR_MATERIAL but all the polys are rendered completely black and I cannot find what is causing them to render like that. This is the code I'm using to set up OGL and SDL:

```
static si GaGlSdlSetup()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) return 0;
    GaPrPrintToConsole("\nSDL Properly initiated");

    l_sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window Test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    /*SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL*/);

    if (l_sdl_window == NULL)
        return 0;
    GaPrPrintToConsole("\nWindow  created");

    // Create an OpenGL context associated with the window.
    SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(l_sdl_window);

    if (glcontext == NULL)
        return 0;
    GaPrPrintToConsole("\nContext created");
   
    return 1;

}

static si GaGlSetup()
{
    const float amb = 0.2f;
    const float LightAmbient[4] = { amb, amb, amb, 1.0f };
    const float LightDiffuse[4] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    const float LightPosition[4] = { 1.0f,  2000.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 35000.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, LightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    return 1;
    
}
```

And this is the basic rendering code. I have confirmed the values for the l_red, l_green and l_blue change according to each vertex and are within the range [0,1], and I'm currently rendering polys without any texture:

```
static si GaGlRender()
{
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    .
    .
    .
    glColor3f(l_red, l_green, l_blue); 
    glVertex3f(l_mesh_vector_1->vx, l_mesh_vector_1->vy, l_mesh_vector_1->vz);

    .
    .
    .
    glColor3f(l_red, l_green, l_blue);  
    glVertex3f(l_mesh_vector_2->vx, l_mesh_vector_2->vy, l_mesh_vector_2->vz);

    .
    .
    .
    glColor3f(l_red, l_green, l_blue);
    glVertex3f(l_mesh_vector_3->vx, l_mesh_vector_3->vy, l_mesh_vector_3->vz);

    .
    .
    .
    glColor3f(l_red, l_green, l_blue); 
    glVertex3f(l_mesh_vector_4->vx, l_mesh_vector_4->vy, l_mesh_vector_4->vz);

    glEnd();

    .
    .
    .
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    
    
}
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

EDIT1:
I added the directional light because I could not get any vertex color to be displayed by using only GL_COLOR_MATERIAL, disabling the lights and leaving only GL_COLOR_MATERIAL displays the same result

EDIT2:
Found the culprit: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) I thought you could leave it on and it would affect only textured polys, but apparently not...

Comment: Your geometry has no normal vectors. When you use a light model, then you have to specify the normal vector for each face or vertex ([`glNormal`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml))

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have actually added the directional light because I could not get GL_COLOR_MATERIAL to show any color. Isn't there an option to display the vertex color of each vertex only? I have deactivated the lights and still renders black. Or normals are needed to display vertex colors using GL_COLOR_MATERIAL too?

Comment: The ambient light is independent of the normal vector.

Comment: That's what I though, so if I disable the lighting and set glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
 glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); it shouldn't need any normal to display the vertex colors right?

Comment: Found the culprit: glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) I thought you could leave it on and it would affect only textured polys, but apparently not...